# Parsing JSON in android showing mismatch error

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse data from Oxford dictionary. However, I'm getting value not found error.

```
{
  "id": "ace",
  "metadata": {
    "operation": "retrieve",
    "provider": "Oxford University Press",
    "schema": "RetrieveEntry"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "ace",
      "language": "en-gb",
      "lexicalEntries": [
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "homographNumber": "100",
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "a playing card with a single spot on it, ranked as the highest card in its suit in most card games"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.006"
                },
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "a person who excels at a particular sport or other activity"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.010",
                  "subsenses": [
                    {
                      "definitions": [
                        "a pilot who has shot down many enemy aircraft"
                      ],
                      "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.011"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "(in tennis and similar games) a service that an opponent is unable to return and thus wins a point"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.013",
                  "subsenses": [
                    {
                      "definitions": [
                        "a hole in one"
                      ],
                      "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.014"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "noun",
            "text": "Noun"
          },
          "text": "ace"
        },
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "homographNumber": "101",
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "very good"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.016"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "adjective",
            "text": "Adjective"
          },
          "text": "ace"
        },
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "homographNumber": "102",
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "(in tennis and similar games) serve an ace against (an opponent)"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.020",
                  "subsenses": [
                    {
                      "definitions": [
                        "score an ace on (a hole) or with (a shot)"
                      ],
                      "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.026"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "achieve high marks in (a test or exam)"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.028",
                  "subsenses": [
                    {
                      "definitions": [
                        "outdo someone in a competitive situation"
                      ],
                      "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.029"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "verb",
            "text": "Verb"
          },
          "text": "ace"
        }
      ],
      "type": "headword",
      "word": "ace"
    },
    {
      "id": "ace",
      "language": "en-gb",
      "lexicalEntries": [
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "homographNumber": "200",
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "a person who has no sexual feelings or desires"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus1190638.004"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "noun",
            "text": "Noun"
          },
          "text": "ace"
        },
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "homographNumber": "201",
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "(of a person) having no sexual feelings or desires; asexual"
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus1190638.006"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "adjective",
            "text": "Adjective"
          },
          "text": "ace"
        }
      ],
      "type": "headword",
      "word": "ace"
    }
  ],
  "word": "ace"
}
```

This is my java code I'm using to parse the data. This code is not complete yet. However, I'm just trying to test the starting decode phase.

```
 //data is string
 OfflineWordItems o = new OfflineWordItems();
        try{
            JSONObject o0 = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray a1 = o0.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i<a1.length(); i++){
                JSONObject o2 = a1.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray a2 = o2.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");
                for(int i2 = 0; i2<a2.length(); i2++){
                    JSONObject o3 = a2.getJSONObject(i2);
                    JSONArray a3 = o3.getJSONArray("entries");
                    for(int i3 = 0; i3<a3.length(); i3++){
                        JSONObject o4 = a3.getJSONObject(i3);
                        JSONArray a4 = o4.getJSONArray("senses");
                        for(int i4=0; i4<a4.length(); i4++){
                            JSONObject o5 = a4.getJSONObject(i4);
                            o.definition = o5.getString("definitions");
                        }
                    }
                    JSONObject o6 = o3.getJSONObject("lexicalCategory");
                    o.lexicalCategoryId = o6.getString("id");
                    o.lexicalCategoryText = o6.getString("text");
                }
            }
            return o;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

This is the error I'm getting. I've tried other decode pattern. Then it showed mismatch type error.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for results
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:587)
```

EDIT:
Even if I write just these lines:

```java
JSONObject o0 = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray a1 = o0.getJSONArray("results");
```

I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: o.definition = o5.getString("definitions"); actually definitions is an array as per your JSON, try running that in forloop to get the data

Comment: what are you getting in data that you are passing to jsonobject

Comment: The error starts at the beginning with the parsing of "Result".

Comment: It says W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for results

Comment: can explain this line -> JSONObject o0 = new JSONObject(data); what is data here, because you are getting json object value as result so you need not to make json object with that

Comment: @AshishSingh, Just change `JSONObject o4 = a1.getJSONObject(i3);` to `JSONObject o4 = a3.getJSONObject(i3);` and you will get the response, as `JSONObject o4 = a1.getJSONObject(i3);` will give you `org.json.JSONException: No value for senses` exception

Comment: @PeterAlwin data is string

Comment: @RakeshKumar, thank you for pointing out. But still getting the same error

Comment: @AshishSingh i updated my answer check now ,try to use valid object names that will clear understanding

Comment: create model/pojo class and use GSON to map data

Answer (score 1):

```
this work for JSONObject:


   JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(data);

                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

               JSONArray  
          jsonArray1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");

                    for(int j=0;j<jsonArray1.length();j++){

                        JSONArray 
            jsonArray2=jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("entries");

                        for(int k=0;k<jsonArray2.length();k++){

                            JSONArray 
                 jsonArray3=jsonArray2.getJSONObject(k).getJSONArray("senses");

                            for(int l=0;l<jsonArray3.length();l++){

                                JSONArray 
               jsonArray4=jsonArray3.getJSONObject(l).getJSONArray("definitions");

                                for(int m=0;m<jsonArray4.length();m++){

                                    JSONObject 
                 definitionsJsonObject=jsonArray4.getJSONObject(m);

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Still same error: m W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for results
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:587)

Answer (score 1):

```
   OfflineWordItems o = new OfflineWordItems();
            try {
                   JSONObject dataobj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray results = dataobj.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject resultsJSONObject = results.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray lexicalEntries = resultsJSONObject.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < lexicalEntries.length(); i2++) {
                JSONObject lexicalEntriesJSONObject = lexicalEntries.getJSONObject(i2);
                JSONArray entries = lexicalEntriesJSONObject.getJSONArray("entries");
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < entries.length(); i3++) {
                    JSONObject entriesJSONObject = entries.getJSONObject(i3);
                    JSONArray senses = entriesJSONObject.getJSONArray("senses");
                    for (int i4 = 0; i4 < senses.length(); i4++) {
                        JSONObject o5 = senses.getJSONObject(i4);
                    }
                }
                JSONObject lexicalCategory = lexicalEntriesJSONObject.getJSONObject("lexicalCategory");

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just change `JSONObject o4 = a1.getJSONObject(i3);` to `JSONObject o4 = a3.getJSONObject(i3);` and you will get the response, as `JSONObject o4 = a1.getJSONObject(i3);` will give you `org.json.JSONException: No value for senses exception`**

```
String response = "{\n" +
                "    \"id\": \"ace\",\n" +
                "    \"metadata\": {\n" +
                "        \"operation\": \"retrieve\",\n" +
                "        \"provider\": \"Oxford University Press\",\n" +
                "        \"schema\": \"RetrieveEntry\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"results\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"id\": \"ace\",\n" +
                "            \"language\": \"en-gb\",\n" +
                "            \"lexicalEntries\": [\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"entries\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"homographNumber\": \"100\",\n" +
                "                            \"senses\": [\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"a playing card with a single spot on it, ranked as the highest card in its suit in most card games\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.006\"\n" +
                "                                },\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"a person who excels at a particular sport or other activity\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.010\",\n" +
                "                                    \"subsenses\": [\n" +
                "                                        {\n" +
                "                                            \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                                \"a pilot who has shot down many enemy aircraft\"\n" +
                "                                            ],\n" +
                "                                            \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.011\"\n" +
                "                                        }\n" +
                "                                    ]\n" +
                "                                },\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"(in tennis and similar games) a service that an opponent is unable to return and thus wins a point\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.013\",\n" +
                "                                    \"subsenses\": [\n" +
                "                                        {\n" +
                "                                            \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                                \"a hole in one\"\n" +
                "                                            ],\n" +
                "                                            \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.014\"\n" +
                "                                        }\n" +
                "                                    ]\n" +
                "                                }\n" +
                "                            ]\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ],\n" +
                "                    \"language\": \"en-gb\",\n" +
                "                    \"lexicalCategory\": {\n" +
                "                        \"id\": \"noun\",\n" +
                "                        \"text\": \"Noun\"\n" +
                "                    },\n" +
                "                    \"text\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "                },\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"entries\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"homographNumber\": \"101\",\n" +
                "                            \"senses\": [\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"very good\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.016\"\n" +
                "                                }\n" +
                "                            ]\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ],\n" +
                "                    \"language\": \"en-gb\",\n" +
                "                    \"lexicalCategory\": {\n" +
                "                        \"id\": \"adjective\",\n" +
                "                        \"text\": \"Adjective\"\n" +
                "                    },\n" +
                "                    \"text\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "                },\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"entries\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"homographNumber\": \"102\",\n" +
                "                            \"senses\": [\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"(in tennis and similar games) serve an ace against (an opponent)\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.020\",\n" +
                "                                    \"subsenses\": [\n" +
                "                                        {\n" +
                "                                            \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                                \"score an ace on (a hole) or with (a shot)\"\n" +
                "                                            ],\n" +
                "                                            \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.026\"\n" +
                "                                        }\n" +
                "                                    ]\n" +
                "                                },\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"achieve high marks in (a test or exam)\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.028\",\n" +
                "                                    \"subsenses\": [\n" +
                "                                        {\n" +
                "                                            \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                                \"outdo someone in a competitive situation\"\n" +
                "                                            ],\n" +
                "                                            \"id\": \"m_en_gbus0005680.029\"\n" +
                "                                        }\n" +
                "                                    ]\n" +
                "                                }\n" +
                "                            ]\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ],\n" +
                "                    \"language\": \"en-gb\",\n" +
                "                    \"lexicalCategory\": {\n" +
                "                        \"id\": \"verb\",\n" +
                "                        \"text\": \"Verb\"\n" +
                "                    },\n" +
                "                    \"text\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"type\": \"headword\",\n" +
                "            \"word\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"id\": \"ace\",\n" +
                "            \"language\": \"en-gb\",\n" +
                "            \"lexicalEntries\": [\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"entries\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"homographNumber\": \"200\",\n" +
                "                            \"senses\": [\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"a person who has no sexual feelings or desires\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus1190638.004\"\n" +
                "                                }\n" +
                "                            ]\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ],\n" +
                "                    \"language\": \"en-gb\",\n" +
                "                    \"lexicalCategory\": {\n" +
                "                        \"id\": \"noun\",\n" +
                "                        \"text\": \"Noun\"\n" +
                "                    },\n" +
                "                    \"text\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "                },\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"entries\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"homographNumber\": \"201\",\n" +
                "                            \"senses\": [\n" +
                "                                {\n" +
                "                                    \"definitions\": [\n" +
                "                                        \"(of a person) having no sexual feelings or desires; asexual\"\n" +
                "                                    ],\n" +
                "                                    \"id\": \"m_en_gbus1190638.006\"\n" +
                "                                }\n" +
                "                            ]\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ],\n" +
                "                    \"language\": \"en-gb\",\n" +
                "                    \"lexicalCategory\": {\n" +
                "                        \"id\": \"adjective\",\n" +
                "                        \"text\": \"Adjective\"\n" +
                "                    },\n" +
                "                    \"text\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"type\": \"headword\",\n" +
                "            \"word\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ],\n" +
                "    \"word\": \"ace\"\n" +
                "}";

        try{
            JSONObject o0 = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray a1 = o0.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i<a1.length(); i++){
                JSONObject o2 = a1.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray a2 = o2.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");
                for(int i2 = 0; i2<a2.length(); i2++){
                    JSONObject o3 = a2.getJSONObject(i2);
                    JSONArray a3 = o3.getJSONArray("entries");
                    for(int i3 = 0; i3<a3.length(); i3++){
                        JSONObject o4 = a3.getJSONObject(i3);
                        JSONArray a4 = o4.getJSONArray("senses");
                        for(int i4=0; i4<a4.length(); i4++){
                            JSONObject o5 = a4.getJSONObject(i4);

                            Log.e("-------","---00--"+o5.getString("definitions"));
                        }
                    }
                    JSONObject o6 = o3.getJSONObject("lexicalCategory");
                      Log.e("-------","---11--"+o6.getString("id")+"<<text>>"+o6.getString("text"));

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("-------","---ex---"+e);
        }
```

**See the `Log's` here**
[image]

Comment: @AshishSingh, Did you executed the above piece of code here on the post?

Comment: @AshishSingh, print the `data` on `Log` to be sure that getting fine?

Comment: I did. It's the same response code as I posted in question.

Answer (score 1):

**Please use this code working fine.**

```
  OfflineWordItems o = new OfflineWordItems();
            try{
                JSONObject o0 = new JSONObject(data);
               JSONArray a1 = o0.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i<a1.length(); i++){
             JSONObject o2 = a1.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray a2 = o2.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");
for(int i2 = 0; i2<a2.length(); i2++){
                JSONObject o3 = a2.getJSONObject(i2);
                    JSONArray a3 = o3.getJSONArray("entries");
                   for(int i3 = 0; i3<a3.length(); i3++){`enter code here`
                    JSONObject o4 = a3.getJSONObject(i3);
                       JSONArray a4 = o4.getJSONArray("senses");
                       for(int i4=0; i4<a4.length(); i4++){
                          JSONObject o5 = a4.getJSONObject(i4);
                        o.definition = o5.getString("definitions");
                    }
                }
                JSONObject o6 = o3.getJSONObject("lexicalCategory");
                o.lexicalCategoryId = o6.getString("id");
                o.lexicalCategoryText = o6.getString("text");
                      }
                     }
                  return o;
                       } catch (Exception e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
o5.getJSONArray("definitions").get(0).toString();
```

Instead of

```
o5.getString("definitions");
```

Comment: Still the same error. I think the error lies somewhere here: "    JSONArray a1 = o0.getJSONArray("results");"

Comment: It says W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for results